# How to select an element that contains quote marks?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, double-quotes, single-quotes

How can I use `querySelector` or any other Javascript selector when the element's attribute contains quote marks `"` ?

For example, if I search for an `img` element that has a `src` of `http://www.example.com/abc"def` (yes, an attribute that contains quotes):

```
document.querySelector('img[src="http://www.example.com/abc"def"]');
```

It gets this error:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document':'img[src="http://www.example.com/abc"def"]' is not a valid selector.`

Obviously, my question applies to both single `'` and double `"` quote marks used simultaneously.

Comment: escape it. do note however that it will require two backslashes.

Comment: All the url links can not have quotes by the standard, this characters MUST be urlencoded, so it's not actually `"` but `%22`

Comment: What @Goran.it said. `<img src="http://www.example.com/abc"def">` is rendered like `<img src="http://www.example.com/abc" def"="">` by Chrome

Comment: @Goran.it eh, you're partly correct. querySelector's attribute equals selector is based on the attribute, not the property. the property does in fact get changed as you've stated, however, if it has an actual quote in the attribute, you'll need the quote in the attribute equals selector as well.

Comment: @Mohrn not if you escape it properly in the html.

Comment: @KevinB Well what OP is asking about is when the quote ain't properly escaped in the html

Comment: @Mohrn i mean, no html was provided, so we have no way of knowing that. [It is possible](https://jsfiddle.net/zfL8v6r0/) to have quotes in an html attribute without it breaking the attribute the way you've described.

Comment: @KevinB _that has a src of http://www.example.com/abc"def (yes, an attribute that contains quotes)_ sounds to me like there's an actual quote in there 

Comment: @Mohrn And as my example shows, you can have an actual quote in there and have it still not break the html.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not arguing with that :)

Comment: My question is about any element/attribute, not just `src` of `img`. My oversight that quotes cannot be used in URLs, so the example became confusing. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var test = document.querySelector('img[src="http://www.example.com/abc\\"def"]');`
```

Appears to work, at least for me, on chrome, when I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

replace your quotes with &x22;

```
document.querySelector('img[src="http://www.example.com/abc&x22;def&x22;]');
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15135906/4263440

Answer (score 0):

You can use \ like this, JS should recognice that it's part of the string:

```
document.querySelector('img[src=\"http://www.example.com/abc\"def\"]');
```

Comment: It would require **two** backslashes per quote because if you only have one, it's just going to escape the quote itself, resulting in a string without backslashes.